# How to retain the variable's value of JSP using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying learn to pass the value of a variable to the angularJS.
But for some unknown reason, I am not being able to do.

Below is the .jsp page which I think is correct:

```html
<body >
    <div ng-controller="customersController">
        <label>Value</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model=something></input>
        <button ng-click="punchIt()">click me!</button>
        <br>Obtained value : {{ value }}
    </div>
</body>
```

In the respective .js page, value passed from .jsp file is not getting retained.The first alert function should return assumed : *something's value*,but it is returning assumed : *undefined*.
Below is the .js file:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("getInfo", []);

myApp.controller("customersController", function($scope, $http){

    $scope.punchIt = function ($scope, $http) {

        var data = {Value: $scope.something};
        alert("assumed : "+ $scope.something);
        $http.post("http://localhost:8082/HelloWorldWS/services/HelloWorldImpl",data)
            .success(function (data, status, header) {
                alert("in success " + data);
                $scope.value = data; 
          }).error(function (data) {
                alert("in error method " + status);
                $scope.value = "error "+ data;
         });
        };
});
```

Please suggest some way out.
Thanks.

Comment: `ng-model=something` will obviously not insert a JSP variable.. Isn't there a syntax for writing JSP to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting two variables ($scope and $http) in your `punchIt()` function declaration but not passing these when you call it on button click. Thus inside your `punchit()` function, both $scope and $http variables would be initialized to nothing (read undefined).

You actually dont need to pass these parameters to your function. Your controller already has these services injected in it via your controller declaration.

Also declare/initialize the `name` variable in your controller. Else, if you do not enter anything in the input field and try to access it in your $`scope`, you will retrive it as undefined.

Your code changes would look as below:

```
myApp.controller("customersController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.name=null;
    //OR $scope.name='';
    $scope.punchIt = function () {
    ...
    }


}
```